# Kafka-node connecting to localhost instance of kafka but not connecting to remote kafka server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

I am currently using the driver kafka-node and this is working fine and I do get outputs from messages consumed and in the queue when I run it locally but when i try to connect to an external kafka machine.
Can anyone help with this?

When I do this, I do not get an error, the code just hangs on the terminal without returning anything.
ctrl+c helps me kill this.

Please see the code below.
Thanks

When I do this, I do not

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.Client('SOMEIP_ADRESS:9092'),
//    client = new kafka.Client('localhost:2181'),
    consumer = new Consumer(
        client,
        [
              { topic: 'catTopic', partition: 0 }
            //{ topic: 'dogTopic', partition: 0 }
        ],
        {
            autoCommit: false,
            fromBeginning: true

        }
    );
// how de we get the messages on the queue


// we only ac when we get messages
consumer.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: Make sure the IP and port are correct. Also check if you can actually reach the broker machine (can you ping it?). Also make sure that you broker version is compatible with you client version -- brokers must have same version of must be newer (ie, higher version). Also check the broker logs for error messages.

Comment: Your connecting IP should point to kafka's zookeeper instance not a kafka broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for some reason, this problem is on node-kafka, kafka-node and kafkaesque problem which I have no idea how to solve.

no-kafka works fine with the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

```
var kafka = require('kafka-node');    
    var Producer = kafka.Producer,

        client=new kafka.KafkaClient({kafkaHost: serverip with port}),
        producer = new Producer(client);

    producer.on('ready', function () {
        return callback(null,producer);
    });

    producer.on('error', function (err) {
        return crashed(new Error(err), false);
    });
};
```

make changes in the kafka/config/server.properties in your remote system that you want to connect...
add this below line

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://<myActual IP address>:9092
```

here note that "ip is your remote system ip only not your local system ip"

for example

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.150.150:9092
```

192.168.150.150:9092 is a remote system ip that your connecting.